# How to override methods with different arguments?

Tags: java

I have several subControllers like below. I want to force developers to override run methods based on their needs. I mean all classes that extends MainController must override either run() or run(String command) methods. Is there any way to do this?

I have a base class called MainController

```
public abstract class MainController{
   public abstract void run();
   public abstract void run(String command);
}

public class Sub1Controller extends MainController{
   public void run(){  //Some Codes Here  }
   public void run(String command) {}  //empty method here
}

public class Sub2Controller extends MainController{
   public void run(){} //empty method here
   public void run(String command) {  //Some Codes Here  }
}
```

**EDIT:** Above example nearly solves my problem but I don't want to put empty methods everywhere.

Comment: *How to override methods with different arguments?* That is overloading.

Comment: that abstract keyword already does that, but you are not extending your base class, that's why you don't notice it

Comment: @Ravi I am talking about subControllers that overrides run method.

Comment: @Stultuske sorry my mistake I edited. I don't want to empty methods everywhere. Is there any other way?

Comment: @hellzone you mean it must override one, not the other? not possible. you can, however, add them both, and have one throw an UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: A concrete class has to implement ALL inherited abstract methods .

Comment: "I want to force developers to override run methods based on their needs" - What if a developer doesn't need to override anything? Your question seems to be something like "How do I force a developer to implement at least one method without requiring to implement all?" - is that correct?

Comment: Extend the base class `MainController` in your subclasses `Sub1Controller` and `Sub2Controller`. Then, you'll have to override those abstract methods and you can provide the implementation in your subclasses. Go through Java inheritance to understand more about the topic.

Comment: @Stultuske Yes it must override one and not the other.

Comment: I do not understand what you want to achieve? How would the caller know, which method to call? Why are 2 methods doing different things with different parameter getting the same name?

Comment: If not all of the methods "apply" to everyone, you may want to break this down into smaller interfaces or add a second "level" of inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't force a developer to implement one abstract method without having to implement others as well. You can provide empty default implementations though and let the dev override when needed:

```
//making the class abstract forces the dev to subclass it but not to override any method,
//which might not be necessary anyways.
public abstract class MainController{
  public void run() { }
  public void run(String command) {}
}

public class Sub1Controller extends MainController{
  @Override
  public void run(){  /*override only this method*/  }
}
```

*Forcing* a developer to only override one method but not the other isn't really possible at all. The problem is that every concrete class needs to implement every method and thus you *have* to provide implementations - either by providing them by default or by forcing the developer to provide them even if they're not needed.

However, your question indicates a design flaw: if the dev would only be required to implement one of those methods how would you make sure the correct one (the one that's being called) is overridden? You could theoretically call both but how would you prevent the dev from providing implementations for / overriding both methods?

Thus a different design might be better suited. Proposing one is hard though without knowing more of the context. One way might be to provide only one method that takes a parameter object that represents all possible parameters and let the dev decide which parameters to use. Another option might be to use multiple interfaces (each containing one method) and let the dev implement those (albeit they could still implement multiple interfaces in the same class).

Example of option 1 (one method only) using generics:

```
public interface Command {}

public interface MainController<T extends Command> {
  public void run( T command );
}

public class Sub1Command implements Command { ... }

public class Sub1Controller implements MainController<Sub1Command> {
  public void run( Sub1Command command ) { ... }
}
```

In the example I'm using generics to define the type of command parameter being passed. Thus the implementation can define which type of commands the `run()` method should accept (calling might be a bit more complex but again the context is missing).

To support a method similar to `run()` you could provide an empty implementation like `VoidCommand implements Command` and then `Sub2Controller implements MainController<VoidCommand>`.

Comment: This solution is working but now problem is I am not forcing developers to override my methods and They can not know if they must override it or not?

Answer (score 0):

The question is: *Why do you need both versions of that method in your interface?*

I suspect that this is w wrong understanding of *ease of use*.

The much more  convenient solution would be to provide a special `NO_COMMAD` constant for the cases the command is not needed:

```
 public interface MyInterface {
    public static final String NO_COMMAD = "";
    public void run(String command);
}
```

This solves your problem of having alternative method signatures.

---

The even betetr possibility would be to create different interfaces where one has a parameter in the methos signature and the other has not:

```
 public interface MyInterfaceWithParam {
    public void run(String command);
}

 public interface MyInterfaceWithoutParam {
    public void run();
}
```